# How to put multiple pickles files in a single pickle file

Tags: python

I have two pickle files that are contain a list of numpy ndarrays.

first pickle file:

```
{'encodings': [array([-0.18668848,  0.09167872,  0.02361359, -0.04610855, -0.11987427,
       -0.06734911,  0.00542389,  0.02105863,  0.17828396, -0.00141097,
        0.166828s45, -0.01075029, -0.20508201,  0.02762154, -0.00806585,
        0.098497  , -0.17736666, -0.11334869, -0.10142692, -0.1134191 ,
        0.06917755,  0.07989676, -0.04121129,  0.04280601, -0.12306173,
       -0.29819348, -0.07650399, -0.10041754,  0.02334423, -0.06270325,
        0.12638046,  0.10296188, -0.10587093, -0.08311734,  0.06213638,
        0.08304631, -0.03443629, -0.08486824,  0.23685798,  0.01827276,
       -0.10278646,  0.01152256,  0.08467054,  0.37257931,  0.15582474,
        0.02709438,  0.04016857, -0.08466265,  0.14121686, -0.27717495,
        0.13716345,  0.18896437,  0.05110805,  0.106585  ,  0.15150583,
       -0.1350172 ,  0.02701535,  0.14240757, -0.17536291,  0.07862181,
        0.06092819,  0.00497432, -0.03655054, -0.15420173,  0.1805391 ,
        0.10382829, -0.07878115, -0.08832525,  0.15745324, -0.07997591,
       -0.13981505,  0.04213319, -0.19279024, -0.15900737, -0.29393584,
        0.10862678,  0.41602921,  0.15656555, -0.11855101,  0.04216752,
       -0.0232455 , -0.03370954,  0.0355633 ,  0.03816839, -0.13917619,
       -0.06723036, -0.04189514,  0.11147611,  0.1995673 ,  0.03261004,
       -0.10638862,  0.1559474 ,  0.05621403, -0.05708034,  0.0482568 ,
        0.01418147, -0.04671318, -0.06601512, -0.20332824, -0.0691556 ,
        0.12811929, -0.07675947, -0.01019647,  0.12645237, -0.19479996,
        0.10532782,  0.03804317, -0.04418825, -0.06108642,  0.02885859,
       -0.15403567,  0.05608891,  0.19509147, -0.15066354,  0.22698388,
        0.12219262,  0.05469556,  0.15206271,  0.06922045,  0.04643065,
       -0.02632714, -0.01712689, -0.09087028, -0.06960677,  0.08032852,
        0.13741611,  0.06458308,  0.07958878])], 'names': ['tom']}
```

second pickle file:

```
{'encodings': [array([-1.10906549e-01,  2.82760076e-02,  1.40928570e-02, -7.55623430e-02,
       -1.18420059e-02, -6.79435134e-02,  7.94159248e-04, -2.11588703e-02,
        1.68759167e-01, -6.51913695e-03,  1.54918343e-01,  2.80910246e-02,
       -2.08628818e-01, -2.71124691e-02,  2.27540880e-02,  3.07342559e-02,
       -1.96070462e-01, -9.49537754e-02, -8.10625032e-02, -8.46448690e-02,
        3.26108336e-02,  4.36929706e-03,  4.52538766e-02,  1.06669012e-02,
       -1.42774120e-01, -3.27435136e-01, -9.54359397e-02, -1.95318609e-01,
        6.05729260e-02, -7.79287443e-02,  6.29613698e-02, -1.52168227e-02,
       -1.35686964e-01, -3.66957076e-02,  2.39675865e-04,  4.68941033e-02,
       -4.50511239e-02, -3.71131971e-02,  1.89375550e-01,  4.80678454e-02,
       -1.22665457e-01, -3.68929692e-02, -3.50655429e-03,  3.41097176e-01,
        1.51335686e-01,  8.24191347e-02,  9.05722976e-02, -2.97215953e-03,
        1.33755967e-01, -2.90517062e-01,  1.33845448e-01,  9.89130512e-02,
        6.75613731e-02,  3.23878974e-02,  1.52221993e-01, -1.62803844e-01,
        8.13175887e-02,  1.11765333e-01, -2.38216847e-01,  1.41546726e-01,
        9.62506086e-02,  3.70164961e-03, -5.48346117e-02,  3.90823977e-03,
        2.20120877e-01,  1.01806007e-01, -1.14795811e-01, -1.18746825e-01,
        7.93062896e-02, -1.68676943e-01, -1.02184657e-02,  8.04015025e-02,
       -1.35200977e-01, -1.91683397e-01, -2.35828787e-01,  1.02385968e-01,
        4.50523496e-01,  1.27005681e-01, -7.58898705e-02,  4.50269431e-02,
       -5.20654880e-02, -4.20882925e-02,  1.13409899e-01,  6.25026077e-02,
       -1.17209882e-01,  2.94286814e-02, -1.15291528e-01,  5.63262142e-02,
        1.39795944e-01, -1.62808914e-02, -4.35662456e-02,  1.33413598e-01,
       -3.00255269e-02, -1.28360288e-02, -3.27749550e-03,  8.85868631e-03,
       -1.23581521e-01,  4.58956361e-02, -5.75632229e-02,  6.86901249e-03,
        1.01847328e-01, -7.13049620e-02, -4.22733976e-03,  5.29949181e-02,
       -1.64895400e-01,  1.34815559e-01, -2.89627630e-02, -6.24453239e-02,
       -3.33562531e-02, -2.41741575e-02, -9.46198851e-02, -3.14747319e-02,
        1.33324310e-01, -2.73984402e-01,  1.59612253e-01,  2.19413936e-01,
        4.25861105e-02,  1.33684829e-01, -2.11685020e-02, -3.15915793e-04,
        1.95543766e-02,  8.47738683e-02, -1.88602582e-01, -2.10027974e-02,
       -6.66024908e-03,  2.21308358e-02, -1.30187161e-03, -5.09036798e-03])], 'names': ['jack']}
```

i want to have:

```
{'encodings': [array([-1.10906549e-01,  2.82760076e-02,  1.40928570e-02, -7.55623430e-02,
       -1.18420059e-02, -6.79435134e-02,  7.94159248e-04, -2.11588703e-02,
        1.68759167e-01, -6.51913695e-03,  1.54918343e-01,  2.80910246e-02,
       -2.08628818e-01, -2.71124691e-02,  2.27540880e-02,  3.07342559e-02,
       -1.96070462e-01, -9.49537754e-02, -8.10625032e-02, -8.46448690e-02,
        3.26108336e-02,  4.36929706e-03,  4.52538766e-02,  1.06669012e-02,
       -1.42774120e-01, -3.27435136e-01, -9.54359397e-02, -1.95318609e-01,
        6.05729260e-02, -7.79287443e-02,  6.29613698e-02, -1.52168227e-02,
       -1.35686964e-01, -3.66957076e-02,  2.39675865e-04,  4.68941033e-02,
       -4.50511239e-02, -3.71131971e-02,  1.89375550e-01,  4.80678454e-02,
       -1.22665457e-01, -3.68929692e-02, -3.50655429e-03,  3.41097176e-01,
        1.51335686e-01,  8.24191347e-02,  9.05722976e-02, -2.97215953e-03,
        1.33755967e-01, -2.90517062e-01,  1.33845448e-01,  9.89130512e-02,
        6.75613731e-02,  3.23878974e-02,  1.52221993e-01, -1.62803844e-01,
        8.13175887e-02,  1.11765333e-01, -2.38216847e-01,  1.41546726e-01,
        9.62506086e-02,  3.70164961e-03, -5.48346117e-02,  3.90823977e-03,
        2.20120877e-01,  1.01806007e-01, -1.14795811e-01, -1.18746825e-01,
        7.93062896e-02, -1.68676943e-01, -1.02184657e-02,  8.04015025e-02,
       -1.35200977e-01, -1.91683397e-01, -2.35828787e-01,  1.02385968e-01,
        4.50523496e-01,  1.27005681e-01, -7.58898705e-02,  4.50269431e-02,
       -5.20654880e-02, -4.20882925e-02,  1.13409899e-01,  6.25026077e-02,
       -1.17209882e-01,  2.94286814e-02, -1.15291528e-01,  5.63262142e-02,
        1.39795944e-01, -1.62808914e-02, -4.35662456e-02,  1.33413598e-01,
       -3.00255269e-02, -1.28360288e-02, -3.27749550e-03,  8.85868631e-03,
       -1.23581521e-01,  4.58956361e-02, -5.75632229e-02,  6.86901249e-03,
        1.01847328e-01, -7.13049620e-02, -4.22733976e-03,  5.29949181e-02,
       -1.64895400e-01,  1.34815559e-01, -2.89627630e-02, -6.24453239e-02,
       -3.33562531e-02, -2.41741575e-02, -9.46198851e-02, -3.14747319e-02,
        1.33324310e-01, -2.73984402e-01,  1.59612253e-01,  2.19413936e-01,
        4.25861105e-02,  1.33684829e-01, -2.11685020e-02, -3.15915793e-04,
        1.95543766e-02,  8.47738683e-02, -1.88602582e-01, -2.10027974e-02,
       -6.66024908e-03,  2.21308358e-02, -1.30187161e-03, -5.09036798e-03]), array([-0.18668848,  0.09167872,  0.02361359, -0.04610855, -0.11987427,
       -0.06734911,  0.00542389,  0.02105863,  0.17828396, -0.00141097,
        0.16682845, -0.01075029, -0.20508201,  0.02762154, -0.00806585,
        0.098497  , -0.17736666, -0.11334869, -0.10142692, -0.1134191 ,
        0.06917755,  0.07989676, -0.04121129,  0.04280601, -0.12306173,
       -0.29819348, -0.07650399, -0.10041754,  0.02334423, -0.06270325,
        0.12638046,  0.10296188, -0.10587093, -0.08311734,  0.06213638,
        0.08304631, -0.03443629, -0.08486824,  0.23685798,  0.01827276,
       -0.10278646,  0.01152256,  0.08467054,  0.37257931,  0.15582474,
        0.02709438,  0.04016857, -0.08466265,  0.14121686, -0.27717495,
        0.13716345,  0.18896437,  0.05110805,  0.106585  ,  0.15150583,
       -0.1350172 ,  0.02701535,  0.14240757, -0.17536291,  0.07862181,
        0.06092819,  0.00497432, -0.03655054, -0.15420173,  0.1805391 ,
        0.10382829, -0.07878115, -0.08832525,  0.15745324, -0.07997591,
       -0.13981505,  0.04213319, -0.19279024, -0.15900737, -0.29393584,
        0.10862678,  0.41602921,  0.15656555, -0.11855101,  0.04216752,
       -0.0232455 , -0.03370954,  0.0355633 ,  0.03816839, -0.13917619,
       -0.06723036, -0.04189514,  0.11147611,  0.1995673 ,  0.03261004,
       -0.10638862,  0.1559474 ,  0.05621403, -0.05708034,  0.0482568 ,
        0.01418147, -0.04671318, -0.06601512, -0.20332824, -0.0691556 ,
        0.12811929, -0.07675947, -0.01019647,  0.12645237, -0.19479996,
        0.10532782,  0.03804317, -0.04418825, -0.06108642,  0.02885859,
       -0.15403567,  0.05608891,  0.19509147, -0.15066354,  0.22698388,
        0.12219262,  0.05469556,  0.15206271,  0.06922045,  0.04643065,
       -0.02632714, -0.01712689, -0.09087028, -0.06960677,  0.08032852,
        0.13741611,  0.06458308,  0.07958878])], 'names': ['jack', 'tom']}
```

How can i put these two pickle files in a single pickle file so that the 'encodings' in one place and the 'names' are in the same place.
Each encodings is for a corresponding names in the final pickle file.

Comment: could you paste the code what are your trying? why not to club before pickle-ing?

Comment: im trying final_pickle = pickle1 +‌pickle2

Comment: when i print(final['encodings']) i get this error:TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

name the first file as as d1 and second file as d2 and the use the below code ... let me know if this helps.. else i will edit my code again.

have a look on what have i tried can suggested you

```
d1={'encodings': [[-0.18668848,  0.09167872,  0.02361359, -0.04610855, -0.11987427,
       -0.06734911,  0.00542389,  0.02105863,  0.17828396, -0.00141097,
        0.16682845, -0.01075029, -0.20508201,  0.02762154, -0.00806585,
        0.098497  , -0.17736666, -0.11334869, -0.10142692, -0.1134191 ,
        0.06917755,  0.07989676, -0.04121129,  0.04280601, -0.12306173,
       -0.29819348, -0.07650399, -0.10041754,  0.02334423, -0.06270325,
        0.12638046,  0.10296188, -0.10587093, -0.08311734,  0.06213638,
        0.08304631, -0.03443629, -0.08486824,  0.23685798,  0.01827276,
       -0.10278646,  0.01152256,  0.08467054,  0.37257931,  0.15582474,
        0.02709438,  0.04016857, -0.08466265,  0.14121686, -0.27717495,
        0.13716345,  0.18896437,  0.05110805,  0.106585  ,  0.15150583,
       -0.1350172 ,  0.02701535,  0.14240757, -0.17536291,  0.07862181,
        0.06092819,  0.00497432, -0.03655054, -0.15420173,  0.1805391 ,
        0.10382829, -0.07878115, -0.08832525,  0.15745324, -0.07997591,
       -0.13981505,  0.04213319, -0.19279024, -0.15900737, -0.29393584,
        0.10862678,  0.41602921,  0.15656555, -0.11855101,  0.04216752,
       -0.0232455 , -0.03370954,  0.0355633 ,  0.03816839, -0.13917619,
       -0.06723036, -0.04189514,  0.11147611,  0.1995673 ,  0.03261004,
       -0.10638862,  0.1559474 ,  0.05621403, -0.05708034,  0.0482568 ,
        0.01418147, -0.04671318, -0.06601512, -0.20332824, -0.0691556 ,
        0.12811929, -0.07675947, -0.01019647,  0.12645237, -0.19479996,
        0.10532782,  0.03804317, -0.04418825, -0.06108642,  0.02885859,
       -0.15403567,  0.05608891,  0.19509147, -0.15066354,  0.22698388,
        0.12219262,  0.05469556,  0.15206271,  0.06922045,  0.04643065,
       -0.02632714, -0.01712689, -0.09087028, -0.06960677,  0.08032852,
        0.13741611,  0.06458308,  0.07958878]], 'names': ['tom']}
d2={'encodings': [[-1.10906549e-01,  2.82760076e-02,  1.40928570e-02, -7.55623430e-02,
       -1.18420059e-02, -6.79435134e-02,  7.94159248e-04, -2.11588703e-02,
        1.68759167e-01, -6.51913695e-03,  1.54918343e-01,  2.80910246e-02,
       -2.08628818e-01, -2.71124691e-02,  2.27540880e-02,  3.07342559e-02,
       -1.96070462e-01, -9.49537754e-02, -8.10625032e-02, -8.46448690e-02,
        3.26108336e-02,  4.36929706e-03,  4.52538766e-02,  1.06669012e-02,
       -1.42774120e-01, -3.27435136e-01, -9.54359397e-02, -1.95318609e-01,
        6.05729260e-02, -7.79287443e-02,  6.29613698e-02, -1.52168227e-02,
       -1.35686964e-01, -3.66957076e-02,  2.39675865e-04,  4.68941033e-02,
       -4.50511239e-02, -3.71131971e-02,  1.89375550e-01,  4.80678454e-02,
       -1.22665457e-01, -3.68929692e-02, -3.50655429e-03,  3.41097176e-01,
        1.51335686e-01,  8.24191347e-02,  9.05722976e-02, -2.97215953e-03,
        1.33755967e-01, -2.90517062e-01,  1.33845448e-01,  9.89130512e-02,
        6.75613731e-02,  3.23878974e-02,  1.52221993e-01, -1.62803844e-01,
        8.13175887e-02,  1.11765333e-01, -2.38216847e-01,  1.41546726e-01,
        9.62506086e-02,  3.70164961e-03, -5.48346117e-02,  3.90823977e-03,
        2.20120877e-01,  1.01806007e-01, -1.14795811e-01, -1.18746825e-01,
        7.93062896e-02, -1.68676943e-01, -1.02184657e-02,  8.04015025e-02,
       -1.35200977e-01, -1.91683397e-01, -2.35828787e-01,  1.02385968e-01,
        4.50523496e-01,  1.27005681e-01, -7.58898705e-02,  4.50269431e-02,
       -5.20654880e-02, -4.20882925e-02,  1.13409899e-01,  6.25026077e-02,
       -1.17209882e-01,  2.94286814e-02, -1.15291528e-01,  5.63262142e-02,
        1.39795944e-01, -1.62808914e-02, -4.35662456e-02,  1.33413598e-01,
       -3.00255269e-02, -1.28360288e-02, -3.27749550e-03,  8.85868631e-03,
       -1.23581521e-01,  4.58956361e-02, -5.75632229e-02,  6.86901249e-03,
        1.01847328e-01, -7.13049620e-02, -4.22733976e-03,  5.29949181e-02,
       -1.64895400e-01,  1.34815559e-01, -2.89627630e-02, -6.24453239e-02,
       -3.33562531e-02, -2.41741575e-02, -9.46198851e-02, -3.14747319e-02,
        1.33324310e-01, -2.73984402e-01,  1.59612253e-01,  2.19413936e-01,
        4.25861105e-02,  1.33684829e-01, -2.11685020e-02, -3.15915793e-04,
        1.95543766e-02,  8.47738683e-02, -1.88602582e-01, -2.10027974e-02,
       -6.66024908e-03,  2.21308358e-02, -1.30187161e-03, -5.09036798e-03]], 'names': ['jack']}
d3={key: value + d2[key]  for key, value in d1.iteritems()}
d3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: thanks,but i can't I can not do this d. I have an array.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
i have this error again

Comment: if i have multiple data dictionary how i do it?for example d1,d2,d3, ...